# How to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 database to newly installed SQL Server 2008 R2 instance?

Tags: sql-server, restore

Our SQL database server recently suffered a serious OS failure and had to be reinstalled from scratch. We are now attempting to associate the restored database and transaction log files into the new instance of SQL Server.

Our backups are up to date and contain the following two files:

- Database.mdf (Primary data file: 170 MB)
- Database.ldf (Transaction log file: 837 MB)

I know this is quite a basic question but I believe it is not a duplicate, is relevant and could be of great value to anyone browsing this site looking for similar answers.

The server is running SBS 2003 SP2 (x86).

Please let me know if I need to update this question with more information.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a database backup performed with the SQL Server BACKUP command?  Executing a RESTORE command from SQL Server Management Studio will restore the mdf and ldf files, and make the database available to the instance.

Comment: Having a Database.mdf and Database.ldf file is not necessarily a good backup. It depends on how the copy of the files were made. The copy needs to be made when no activity was taking place on the database.  Otherwise, the files *might* not be in a consistent state when reattached. Using SQL Server BACKUP and RESTORE commands (or 3rd party equivalents) is a much safer strategy.

Comment: @RLF: The database was backed up in the middle of the night when all workstations in the office were shut down. No activity would have taken place on the database for many hours prior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio and attach the database using GUI as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx#SSMSProcedure).

Or using T-SQL, change the path to your drive & folder accordingly.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase
    ON (FILENAME = 'D:\MySQLServer\Database.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'D:\MySQLServer\Database.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176061(v=sql.105).aspx.

The SQL Server Service Account needs read/write permission to those folders used to store the database files.

More reading on security and permission required at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190209(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Don't forget since you've moved to a new instance you will need to grant the user accounts access again at the instance level. If they are AD accounts you can just add them to the instance, if they are SQL accounts, you need to "resync" the logins. It's discussed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229883/sync-sql-logins-utility-on-2005-2008

Comment: @CleanFill: I'm not 100% sure if they are SQL or AD accounts but am assuming SQL accounts. When the database was originally created by someone else, they polled AD to create a list of users based on AD usernames that existed at the time; however, AD changes which occurred subsequently have not been reflected in the account list

Comment: @CleanFil do I need to manually recreate all the SQL accounts again under Security -> Logins?

Comment: I can confirm they are AD accounts rather than SQL (or mixed).

Comment: you can give permission to your AD user group, as shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029014/how-to-add-active-directory-user-group-as-login-in-sql-server